# Can a Value of an object filter be edited by apex code?

Tags: apex, roll-up-summary

I have a Roll-up summary field on an object, it has a filter by year number. I want instead of manually change that number, create a batchable that i can execute to change this value. Is that possible?

In Accounts I have this custom field:
`<fields>
        <fullName>Objetivo_Ano_Actual__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Objetivo Año Actual</label>
        <summarizedField>Objetivos__c.Objetivo__c</summarizedField>
        <summaryFilterItems>
            <field>Objetivos__c.Ano__c</field>
            <operation>equals</operation>
            <value>2015</value>
        </summaryFilterItems>
        <summaryForeignKey>Objetivos__c.Cliente__c</summaryForeignKey>
        <summaryOperation>sum</summaryOperation>
        <type>Summary</type>
    </fields>`

I wonder how could i on a batchable apex code modify the 2015 value.

Thank you.

Comment: Recognize that if you implemented something like what you're asking about using Apex to do, those changes wouldn't show up in your Org's Setup and Audit Trail Logs when looking back to see what's changed; something which might be important later when troubleshooting issues.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't be a problem at all, as far as i know about the needs of what we're trying to do. But i still can't find where can i edit this values, if it's possible, which i'm not sure.

Thanks anyway for the advice!

Comment: can you use a boolean on the detail object called is_rollupable_year__c?  Set via workflows or triggers; reset on prior year's detail records via data loader at end of year?